# Moving files from a linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

My goal is to write a kernel module that deletes the binary for /bin/ps and then moves and renames a file from the /tmp directory to replace ps in the /bin directory. It's basically a proof of concept of a rootkit that replaces a utility. I'm trying to find either functions that duplicate the functionality of link() and unlink(). I haven't been able to find any functions defined by the kernel that do that. Is that a possibility? Or would I have to do something like manually modifying dentrys?

Comment: It's harder than that, because `/bin` and `/tmp` will typically be on separate filesystems (`/tmp` is usually a ramdisk on modern systems).  So `link/unlink` and `rename` will not suffice.  You'll have to duplicate the functionality of userspace `mv(1)` which actually reads all the bytes from the source file and writes them to the destination.  This is something the kernel normally leaves to userspace, so you won't find code specifically for that purpose in the kernel.  However the functions that implement `splice(2)` might help, I'm not sure.

Comment: @NateEldredge you probably want `sendfile(2)` instead of `splice(2)`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot.